# Jquery Animate won't change color

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am working on a website utlizing Jquery. I know Jquery works because I have tested it on other elements but for some reason I can't animate a button to change color.

This is the javascript for the button.

```
if (GlobalPublic.innerHTML == "Global") {
            //fade to background color #018749, and inner html "Personal" with jquery
            $(GlobalPublic).animate({
                backgroundColor: "#018749"
            }, 250);
            GlobalPublic.innerHTML = "Personal";
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<button id="GlobalToggle" onclick="Toggle()">Global</button>
```

And this is the CSS for the button:

```
#GlobalToggle {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #0A66C2;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-family: "Lemon/Milk", system-ui, system-ui, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", "Fira Sans", Ubuntu, Oxygen, "Oxygen Sans", Cantarell, "Droid Sans", "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  max-width: 480px;
  min-height: 40px;
  min-width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
        top: 60%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

1. In your code , you choose wrong id (`$(GlobalPublic)`).
2. Don't forgot to include jQueryUI.
3. Suggestion , don't mismatch jQuery and JavaScript.

Example (jQuery):

```js
function Toggle() {
  var $gb = $("#GlobalToggle");
  if ($gb.text() == "Global");
  $($gb).animate({
    backgroundColor: "#018749",
    width: 90
  }, 2500);
  $gb.text("Personal");
}
```

```css
#GlobalToggle {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #0A66C2;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-family: "Lemon/Milk", system-ui, system-ui, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", "Fira Sans", Ubuntu, Oxygen, "Oxygen Sans", Cantarell, "Droid Sans", "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  max-width: 480px;
  min-height: 40px;
  min-width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<button id="GlobalToggle" onclick="Toggle()">Global</button>
```